# Drupal 9 multisite split .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-8, multisite, drupal-9

I am working on Drupal 9 multisite and I want split the `.htaccess` file, one per site to create different redirect rules.

I know that it's possible to add all rules on drupal_root/.htaccess but I prefer to have one `.htaccess` per site.

The structure is:

`drupal_root/sites/site-1/`

`drupal_root/sites/site-2/`

`drupal_root/sites/site-3/`

`drupal_root/sites/site-4/`

and i want add `.htaccess`, for example in `drupal_root/sites/site-1/` and another different in `drupal_root/sites/site-2/`

I tried adding `.htaccess` directly on `drupal_root/sites/site-1/` but it doesn't work.

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dev.{site-1}.com/test/?$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.{site-1}.com/test/?$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dev.{site-1}.com/testredirect [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you accessing the Drupal sites with different domains?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the URLs used to access "site-1" don't actually contain `/sites/site-1/`? In which case the URL would need to be internally rewritten (by Apache) to this directory (or a subdirectory of) for the `/sites/site-1/.htaccess` file to be processed (by Apache) - but I don't believe that happens (since everything is handled by the core Drupal installation in the root - the purpose of having a "multisite" installation).

So, I don't think what you are suggesting is realistically possible I'm afraid (without more work).

Ordinarily you would need to have multiple "separate" Drupal installations to be able to have separate `.htaccess` files.

This would seem to be backed up by the following question on the Drupal SE site, which suggests to use the "Redirect module" to manage per site redirections.

- [Drupal Stack Exchange - Per site htaccess with multisite](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104271/per-site-htaccess-with-multisite)

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dev.{site-1}.com/test/?$ [OR] 
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.{site-1}.com/test/?$ [NC] 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dev.{site-1}.com/testredirect [R,L]
> ```

This rule wouldn't do anything anyway, since the `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the *hostname* from the request only, not the URL-path. But would you need to check the hostname if this `.htaccess` file is intended only to be processed when the user makes requests to "site-1"?

For example, it should be written:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dev.{site-1}\.com.?$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^test/?$ https://www.dev.{site-1}.com/testredirect [R,L]
```